# Can we find a discontinuous function such that $\int_1^x f(t)dt=e^{2x}-e^x$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I was asked to solve the following problem:

> When $\int_a^x f(t)dt=e^{2x}-e^x$, find $a$.

Not written in the problem, but maybe it is rational to suppose that $f$ is an Riemann integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $a$ is real.

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function, then $\int_a^x f(t)dt$ is differentiable and its derivation is $f(x)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Thus $f(x)=2e^{2x}-e^x$ and $\int_a^x f(t)dt=e^{2x}-e^x-(e^{2a}-e^a)$, so we obtain $a=0$.

However, I doubt that it is a ill-posed problem, because I have no evidence that $f$ is continuous, though $\int_a^x f(x)dx$ is differentiable for any $x$. If we can find a discontinuous function $f$ and nonzero $a$ satisfying the condition, then my doubt is correct.

Can we find such function?

Comment: I'm gonna hypothesize that the integral of a discontinuous function will always result in a non-differentiable function, even if it is continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With any reasonable sort of integral, $\int_a^a f(t)\; dt = 0$, so taking $x=a$ you want
$0 = e^{2a} - e^a = e^a (e^a-1)$.  The only real solution is $a=0$.

If you allow complex $a$, $a=2 n \pi i$ works for any integer $n$, in the sense that $\int_\Gamma (2 \exp(2z) - \exp(z))\; dz = \exp(2 x) - \exp(x)$ for any contour $\Gamma$ starting at $2n\pi$ and ending at $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you assume $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable, then $F(x) = \int_a^xf(t)\,dt$ is (locally) absolutely continuous and is thus a.e. differentiable with $F'(x) = f(x)$ a.e. So, at least $f(x) = 2e^{2x}-e^x$ a.e. and also $a = 0$.